# How to stored data in react native like we did in core data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a demo of Storing employee record in app using react native. I have searched about how to store data using react native and I come to know that using  AsyncStorage we can stored data.
So My question is

1.what is the way to store data like we did in core data ios?
2.How did we create multiple tables?
3.How did we established relationship between multiple tables?

Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: You can use apis for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) with [Redux-Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

You can use Async storage to maintain proper structure and Async rendering too (other benefits of redux).

You can do something like

```
const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      whitelist: ['aaaa', 'vvvv'],
    };
```

where storage can be of different types:

- localStorage
- SessionStorage
- Async Storage

  as mentioned in redux persist docs

Also you can blacklist (except) or whitelist (only) certain reducers